# Multiple domains sync to Azure AD

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365

lets say I have two on-premise domains (DomainA.org, domainB.org) and one tenant (domainA.onmicrosoft.com). Both domains are sync thanks to Azure AD Connect, so user from domainA can log to office.com, there is no problem. Hoever user from domainB getting this "Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.", and when I changed password from portal.office.com for this user from domainB. I can log with this new password, but only to office365 services, its not sync to On-prem.

And another wierd thing is, that I cant change password for users from domainA.

Do You know where the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have synced your 2 domains to Azure AD through Azure AD connect . Initially you have registered both the domain in Azure AD and verified both. Kindly check what kind of authentication you were using for Domain A since you were not able to change the password from Azure End. If you have federated that domain it is not possible to change from the cloud. If you were using password hash synchronization then the authentication will happen if cloud and you can change for managed domain.

I request you to go through this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-sspr-writeback) about password writeback .  When you are getting an error message while logging before resetting the password kindly note the correlation ID and time stamp and need to get a support ticket since it will be due to multiple reasons.